# Check if button disabled then alert HTML Onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

well right now I have this checkbox that's enabling / disabling a submit button for my form.

I simply have this code for enabling / disabling it

```
onclick="if(this.checked){this.form.submit_btn.disabled=false}else{this.form.submit_btn.disabled=true};this.blur();"
```

now I'm just wondering how I can make it so that if they click the button when it's disabled, have it alert them with a certain message.

so add an onclick event to the button and have it be like

```
if(this.disabled=true){alert('Button disabled!');}
```

or something similar? I'm pretty new to all the onclick stuff.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is particularly necessary - browsers style disabled buttons to look as such, and seeing as no action is taken (or "button down" styling is applied) when the button is clicked, you don't need another notification telling users the button is disabled.

Comment: onClick wont work when button is disabled, that's the whole point of disabling button. Instead show message inside a span or div above button for accepting the terms (if that's the case) by click on checkbox

Comment: Not too good at JS... But in JQuery you would be able to do mouseenter/hover or so to tip the user that the checkbox needs to be filled. You should even be able to add an click event unlike the OnClick command :)

Comment: well right now the button is being styled with an image that isn't changing, could I have it change the button image when it's disabled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know what it's worth but in jQuery it would go like:

```
// Not tested!    
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myButton').click(function(){
     if($(this).is(':disabled')) { 
         alert('No need to click, it\'s disabled.');
     } 
  });
});
```

Don't see the point though. Why bother someone with a message while the button is already disabled (and the browser is showing so).

Comment: well the reason I need a message is because the button is being styled with an image, the image isn't changing when the button is disabled therefore the users have no way of knowing if the buttons disabled or not, and may think something wrong with the website when they click it and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why not use Javascript (or jQuery so you wish) for changing the background image to some image more indicating that the button cannot be clicked instead of showing a message?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! :) I ended up doing that instead :)

Answer (score 4):

You can't well at least not directly anyway.  When a button is disabled, then it's disabled and that means it also fires no events.

Now.. that said, there is a way you could get round it, if you absolutely have to.

Essentially, you can make it work by using 2 divs and a button like so:

```
    <div>
      <div id="overlay" style="display:hidden; z-order:99999">&nbsp;</div>
      <button id="mybtn">My Button to click</button>
    </div>
```

You set the overlay div's background colour to transparent, and when you disable the button, you unhide the overlay div.

Because the div is transparent, you should see NO change in the button, but clicking on it will result in the clicks getting picked up by the transparent div first.

You would then attach your click handler to the overlay div, and the result is that you can trigger a message that appears (but isn't really) to be being popped up by a click on the disabled button.

Comment: Who ever gave me the -2 for this, I'd like to know your reason why?  It's only fair...

Comment: I don't know why someone would -1 you :O I gave you +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead you may change the image style with gray scale approach.

```
img {
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  filter: grayscale(1); /* Firefox 35+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
}
```